# Unable to get compiled code running due to "collect2: ld returned 1 exit status." error

Tags: windows, qt, phonon

This error is getting displayed after I build the code in compile output section.

```
C:\Qt\2009.04\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: cannot find -lphonond
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status.
mingw32-make[1]: *** [debug\addressbook.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make: *** [debug] Error 2
Exited with code 2.
Error while building project addressbook
When executing build step 'Make'
```

Irrespective of any code I am building, I get this common one. 
I am using windows 7 and Qt 4.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give more details if you want more than passing help.
The relevant pieces of the makefile would be a good start.

Figure out where `libphonond` is stored and pass the path to the linker with `-L` if the path is not already there.

It might be that:

- The lib is not installed.  If you built Qt from source, `libphonond` might not be part of the default build.
- The lib is not configured for linking in the makefile correctly
- You did not build all the debugging libs

There's a place to start anyway...

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Building_the_Phonon_backend_plugin_on_Windows_using_MinGW :

> This article [*Building the Phonon backend plugin on Windows using MinGW*] is obsolete since version 4.6. 
>   Qt by default has phonon support now.

Looking at your build path, you seem to have a version older than 4.6 (which was released on 1 December 2009, whereas you have Qt as of April 2009.04).

In other words : get a newer version of Qt.